# What's the name of such design pattern when doing online banking? Form, Review and Acknowledgement

Tags: web-app, e-commerce

If you could recall how you have been doing online banking like paying the other, or using Paypal/eBay/Amazon or filling in some important questionnaire, you should be familiar with such client side User Interaction design pattern:

1. Filling the **Form** in one or multiple pages.
2. **Preview** All your answers to **confirm**
3. **Submission** then **Acknowledgement**

Just like 3 screenshots below.
Is there an "official" name for such design pattern?
And what could be the reasons behind such common design pattern?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I noticed, when posting this question, I had gone through all these 3 steps/screens of the same design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The interaction design pattern is either Wizard or Multi-Step Form. The content of the steps (review/acknowledgement) is irrelevant to the design pattern.

I would refer to the final step of a wizard that asks the user to confirm before saving or submitting as the "Confirmation Step".

I would refer to the Acknowledgement step as "Success/Failure Feedback".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the flow through which user has to be taken for the intended object to be completed.

Filling up the form is 1st step towards submission of the form. But because the submit action could be (in most cases) an irreversible process, i.e., you cannot undo it, there is a preview option added where user can go through the data before submitting it. Once the submission is done it is important to give feedback to the user (one of the usability heuristics - Visibility of system status) about the status.

I am not sure if there is any term specified for this flow.

Comment: when posting this question, I had gone through all these 3 steps/screens of the same design pattern. And I could edit/revise the question that had been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific name for that but if you still want to call it something then you can go with "Transaction Process" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [multi-step form](https://instapage.com/blog/multi-step-form-part-2/).

Very useful for allowing users to finish your form in bits rather than in an overwhelming whole.

I always reference [TypeForm](https://www.typeform.com) since they built their whole business around making very simple but nice looking multi-step forms.